# Delete treegrid icon

Tags: extjs, icons, treegrid

I won't show treegrid icon each node.

I tried using: 
 1. "iconCls" config, with 'void' value.
 2. Using a 'wrong' value.

Finally, I have the same that I expected, 'defaults icons' for all rows.

Someone know any form to delete these icons ?

thanks for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure you give an `iconCls` of, say `treenode-no-icon`. I do so in my model:

```
{name: 'iconCls', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'treenode-no-icon'},
```

Then in your css include:

```
.treenode-no-icon
{
    display : none !important;
}
```

Comment: +1. Very nice and simple. But, if I need to show the "non-leaf
" icon?

Comment: You want to show non-leaf to all nodes even if they are leafs?

Comment: No @Izhaki, I want to show only the icons for "father" node and not for leaf node. I have a structure of: 1 father to 'N' Children, only 2 levels.

thx 4 ur time! ;)

Comment: So for leaf nodes set iconCls to be `treenode-no-icon`.

Answer (score 0):

This was a few years ago, but here is a solution using ExtJS 6 that I discovered.

Using a custom theme, in the theme file associated with Ext.tree.View, I added the line:

```
$tree-icon-width : 0px;
```

My treepanel data now displays without any visible icons.